# Window.open if window is not open then call another function + timer

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to open a new window with window.open and if somebody manually closes the window it will call the pause() function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var win = window.open("link.html", "thePopUp", "");
            var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
if (win.closed !== false) { // !== is required for compatibility with Opera
    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
    pause();
}
}, 200);

    </script>
```

BUT for that pause() function to work the user will need to be allowing popups for the window to first open and then to manually close it.

I would like the pause() function to be called if the window was never open in the first place so even if they aren't allowing popups.

Comment: How about using a modal pop up rather than a window pop up?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a pop up window I would recommend using a javascript modal pop up instead.

Here is a demo:

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/demo/modal/modal2.html
- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

  - `Outside HTML (Ajax)` would be the best example for you. Have a look at the source code to see how to call this if this is what you want.

There are many options for this. Here are a couple jquery options:

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
- http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need more of a hand.